# Give app widget button custom colour with rounded rectangle shape

Tags: android, colors, android-appwidget, remoteview, shapedrawable

I've got an app which creates widgets where the user can set the colour of the button's background via a colour picking dialog. However, the only way I can set the button in the remote view to have this colour is by doing this

```
rv.setInt(R.id.button, "setBackgroundColor", colour);
```

but this always makes the background a rectangle shape, replacing any previously set background drawable. What I would like to do is have the button as a rounded-corners rectangle shape which can be set to a custom colour. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: If you have software similar to Photoshop, make some rounded rectangular png images, each with a color that you want and identical size. Then modify them with the android 9 patch editor to be expandable. You can then set the appropriate colored image as the background of your button.

Comment: @HowardHodson I appreciate that that would work, but then I'd have to restrict the colours available, and I personally want to keep the feature than any custom colour can be set, but thanks anyway

Comment: I googled the heck out of your question and found one person that is using transparent images and setting the button backgounds by image name. They were using a selector with img1, img2, and img3. You might want to try that. Otherwise, I don't think there's a current answer out there. Someone from the Google development group will have to take an interest...